# Is it possible to use ribbon camera input as additional USB/ethernet port?

Tags: usb, raspicam, pi-zero

I have an Raspberry Pi Zero and I wonder if I can get more USB ports without concentrator :?

Answer (score 1):

No, the camera input can only be used for cameras or a few video input boards.

If you need usb ports and ethernet how about a combined 3 usb port hub including ethernet: https://www.modmypi.com/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-zero-board-379/rpi-zero-accessories/3-port-usb-hub-w-ethernet-micro-usb-pi-zero/?search=usb%20hub